# How to make hc-sticky plugin to reffer to its container

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have hc-sticky plugin installed on my website, I can use this code to make it work for a scrolling sidebar:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('.panel-rand').hcSticky({
        stickTo: document,
        responsive: true,
        bottomEnd: 985,
        innerTop: 12,
        offResolutions: [-1200]        
    });
});
</script>
```

But the problem is that you can see how it's working in the left side of the window (at this link: http://www.cumseface.eu/viewtopic.php?t=91 ), when you scroll until bottom, the left sidebar doesn`t stop scrolling at the end of the container in which is in. Can somebody help me to fix that ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your container is document not parent element; you set it via 'stickTo' option. In addition, 'bottomEnd: 985' means something like "scroll will stop when between container bottom and stick block bottom will be 985px space".

So you need to change container to element with desired scroll height. Closest to this is '.post.bg2', but you have some additional blocks above the '.panel-rand'. Their sum height is near 65px, therefore I set bottomEnd to 70 for compensation.

Try this:

```
$('.panel-rand').hcSticky({
    stickTo: '.post.bg2',
    responsive: true,
    bottomEnd: 70,
    innerTop: 12,
    offResolutions: [-1200]        
});
```